# SQLAlchemy - proper way to create unsigned BigInteger

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I'm getting a warning now that passing arguments to `BigInteger` is deprecated.  However, I'm not sure of any other way to declare the value as unsigned.  I'm storing the result of MySQL's `uuid_short()` function which is an unsigned 64-bit integer which will likely cause an overflow if the column is not declared as `UNSIGNED`.

What's the proper way of handling this issue now?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

from https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sqlalchemy/L3otXINq6Ts :

you can use `from sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql import BIGINT`

Comment: just for people reviewing this...  I accepted this answer because I got it from jbub on IRC before any other answer on SO.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not familiar quite much with SQLAlchemy. Anyway, as I remember you can set an unsigned integer the following way:

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql import INTEGER
Column(INTEGER(unsigned=True))
```

or just

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql import INTEGER as Integer
Column(Integer(unsigned=True))
```

The same applies to BIGINT.

Comment: You should highlight is some way that you're getting the types from `dialects.mysql`...  I didn't see that at first.

Comment: Well it's clear that I'm importing `INTEGER` from `sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql` not sure how it could be more clearer. Anyway did it work with you? If so, please don't forget to accept the answer.

Comment: Sorry, I just looked at the `Integer(unsigned=True)` and thought you were already doing the same thing I was trying.